# Confetti Color change

Tags: javascript, jquery

first off, I'd like to say that I'm using [Smeegs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1526306/smeegs)'s [Confetti Code](http://jsfiddle.net/vxP5q/61/), but I'm having a problem with changing the color. They have it so that it has an array of colors, but I only want mine to have two specific ones.

I tried using an if statement with a variable like this:

```
if(Math.random() > .3) {
var coolColor = "002147";
}
else {
var coolColor = "FF6319";
};
```

with the color picker:

```
 color: "#" + coolColor,
```

My problem is that I want both colors to show up, not just one, and JS does seem to pick a color, but only one of the colors each time. How can I make it so there is two colors?

Comment: So what is the question. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Oh, sorry! The problem is that I want it to show both colors, but it only shows one. I'll update the question!

Comment: You are putting the `coolColor` in if else condition, there will be only one color at a time. For use two color you need to store it in two different variables from outside of `if else` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the Smeegs' Confetti Code and it seems that he generates the colors with randomizing RGBA, you could replace that line with your color like this:

```
var newRGBA;
for (var i = 0; i < mp; i++) {
    if(Math.random()>.3){
        newRGBA = "rgba(0,21,47,0.7)";
    }else{
        newRGBA = "rgba(255,63,19,0.7)";
    }
    particles.push({
        x: Math.random() * W, //x-coordinate
        y: Math.random() * H, //y-coordinate
        r: randomFromTo(5, 30), //radius
        d: (Math.random() * mp) + 10, //density
        color: newRGBA,                            //changed this line to our variable
        tilt: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) - 10,
        tiltAngleIncremental: (Math.random() * 0.07) + .05,
        tiltAngle: 0
    });
}
```

And it's working: [RESULT](http://jsfiddle.net/5c4z6/)